# Why is the current war on the Middle East called "Israel against Hamas"?

Tags: israel, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, propaganda, rhetoric

As the background, the Gazan military, authorized and directed by the Gazan government, had [attacked it's neighboring Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Hamas-led_attack_on_Israel). As part of the attack, hundreds of Israeli civilians [have been raped, mutilated, murdered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Hamas-led_attack_on_Israel#Reported_atrocities), and some were kidnapped (some kidnapped alive and died in Palestinian custody, some were already dead and their bodies were kidnapped, and some are still alive held hostage by the Palestinian government of Gaza).

Yet, the war is presented as "Israel against Hamas", implying that a) the war was started by Israel, and b) it is against some entity called "Hamas" that has nothing to do with a completely distinct concept of "Palestine".

The [Wikipedia article on the war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war) lists multiple organizations on the Palestinian side:

> - Hamas
> - Palestinian Islamic Jihad
> - Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine
> - Democratic Front for the Liberation of Palestine
> - Al-Aqsa Martyrs' Brigades
> - Popular Resistance Committees
> - PFLP–GC

Why is such a misleading presentation necessary? And if so, why is it "Israel", and not "Likud" to signify the major party as the responsible party and not the government, similarly to how the Palestinian side is represented?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82989/are-there-any-wars-other-than-the-2023-israel-hamas-war-that-are-named-after-a-c

Comment: Thanks, marked as duplicate. I'll leave it here since it's easier to find than the overly verbose description of the other question.